# SAP ECTR /DSCSAG/ Business Add-Ins for SAP S/4HANA 1.1

Tags: s4hana

I am installing the SAP ECTR tool on my machine by following the official installation and configuration guidelines from SAP. However, the /dscsag* related Business Configuration Sets and BAdis do not exist in my SAP ERP system and I have not found in the SAP guidelines how to integrate these sets into the SAP system. I would be very appreciated if someone could help me with this issue.

Kind regards

Comment: Stack Overflow is about programming questions. You'll get better answers in SAP forums (or SuperUser.com).

Comment: if you installed this product correctly, you should all the ECTR objects in your system. Verify the installation in the [component table](https://blogs.sap.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/SAP_BS_FND_001.png), you should see smth like `DSCSAG PLM` there